# Standard FFT classes/library for Android?

Tags: android, signal-processing, fft, frequency, trigonometry

I plan to "visualise" some graphical data via audio. To make it short: I get a bunch of frequencies and related amplitude values out of some image data. This frequency/amplitude table with - lets say 256 pairs of data - has to be converted into related sine-waveforms.

One solution would be to generate sine-waveforms with different frequencies for eeach table entry. That would mean to generate sine waveforms for up to 256 times. But I'd guess that's quite slow. So using FFT-conversion should be a better solution for this?

So my question: is there some kind of fast and easy to use FFT standard available for Android that could be used for this?

Answer (score 6):

In my Android project I used [JTranforms](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) which worked flawlessly on Android.

Example code:

```
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

AudioRecord ar = // initialize AudioRecord here;
ar.startRecording();

// Here's the Fast Fourier Transform from JTransforms
DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(samples.length);

do {
  // Read audio to 'samples' array and convert it to double[]
  ar.read(samples, 0, samples.length);

  // Will store FFT in 'samplesD'
  fft.realForward(samplesD);

} while ( /* condition */ );

ar.stop();
ar.release();
```

---

UPDATE:

It can be found at [**`JTransforms`**](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) that is maintained on *github* [here](https://github.com/wendykierp/JTransforms) and avaiable as a *Maven* plugin [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.wendykierp/JTransforms/3.1).

To use with with recent Gradle versions, do something like:

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    implementation 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.1'
}
```

Comment: I plan to use FFT in other direction (generation of audio data instead of analysing of existing audio data). Does JTransform support that too? I could not find a documentation on their page, so I'm asking...

Comment: The backward way (IFFT) is just the same with the exception of the sign and a normalization factor. So if you have a FFT available you can always use it as IFFT by multiplying the output with the correct factor.

Comment: @kamituel I am also using JTranforms in one of my applications. Can I sell that application on Play Store of does MPL/LGPL/GPL license have some restirictions.

Comment: @kamituel give me any example with jar folder otehr wise provide any line here...

Comment: Any example in android plz give me it is more use full to me

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy - that's all I got. This code is from private app I once wrote which isn't open source, unfortunately. But all you need to do is include JTransforms JAR file so it's included in your APK and use code from my answer.

Comment: @madLokesh Yes, as far as I know the mozilla public license (MPL) allows you to use the code commercially as long as you keep the files from the work which is MPL'd separate (and I think you publish any changes you make to the library, but not sure).
Obviously not a lawyer, check here https://tldrlegal.com/license/mozilla-public-license-2.0-(mpl-2)